# Update custom adapter with query results

Tags: android, adapter

i want to query results from custom adapter by comparing query text with list in RecycleView, it successfully gets results from query then i make list of results and update the existing adapter but it does not effect anything, i use below code fot that

```
combinationMessagesList = createCombinationMessagesList();
    combinationMessages = createCombinationMessagesList();

    combinationMessages.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < combinationMessagesList.size(); i++) {

        CombinationMessage message = combinationMessagesList.get(i);
        if (message.getBody().toString().equals(search.getText().toString())){

            combinationMessages.add(combinationMessagesList.get(i));

        }
    }

    messagesAdapter.setList(combinationmessagesList);
    messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

PrivateDialogActivity

```
public class PrivateDialogActivity extends BaseDialogActivity {

private FriendOperationAction friendOperationAction;
private FriendObserver friendObserver;
private int operationItemPosition;
private final String TAG = "PrivateDialogActivity";

EditText search;

public static void start(Context context, User opponent, Dialog dialog) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrivateDialogActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_OPPONENT, opponent);
    intent.putExtra(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_DIALOG, dialog);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initFields();

    context = this;

    if (dialog == null) {
        finish();
    }

    setUpActionBarWithUpButton();

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        deleteTempMessages();
    }

    addObservers();

    initMessagesRecyclerView();



    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edittext);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult();
        }
    });

}

private void showResult() {

    combinationMessagesList = createCombinationMessagesList();
    combinationMessages = createCombinationMessagesList();

    combinationMessages.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < combinationMessagesList.size(); i++) {

        CombinationMessage message = combinationMessagesList.get(i);
        if (message.getBody().toString().equals(search.getText().toString())){

            combinationMessages.add(combinationMessagesList.get(i));

        }
    }

    messagesAdapter.setList(combinationMessagesList);
    messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
protected void addActions() {
    super.addActions();

    addAction(QBServiceConsts.ACCEPT_FRIEND_SUCCESS_ACTION, new AcceptFriendSuccessAction());
    addAction(QBServiceConsts.ACCEPT_FRIEND_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);

    addAction(QBServiceConsts.REJECT_FRIEND_SUCCESS_ACTION, new RejectFriendSuccessAction());
    addAction(QBServiceConsts.REJECT_FRIEND_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);

    updateBroadcastActionList();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    checkForCorrectChat();

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        startLoadDialogMessages();
    }

    checkMessageSendingPossibility();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    deleteObservers();
}

@Override
protected void updateActionBar() {
    setOnlineStatus(opponentUser);

    checkActionBarLogo(opponentUser.getAvatar(), R.drawable.placeholder_user);
}

@Override
protected void onConnectServiceLocally(QBService service) {
    onConnectServiceLocally();
    setOnlineStatus(opponentUser);
}

@Override
protected void onFileLoaded(QBFile file, String dialogId) {
    if(!dialogId.equals(dialog.getDialogId())){
        return;
    }

    try {
        privateChatHelper.sendPrivateMessageWithAttachImage(file, opponentUser.getUserId(), null, null);
    } catch (QBResponseException exc) {
        ErrorUtils.showError(this, exc);
    }
}

@Override
protected Bundle generateBundleToInitDialog() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_OPPONENT_ID, opponentUser.getUserId());
    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void initMessagesRecyclerView() {
    super.initMessagesRecyclerView();
    messagesAdapter = new PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter(this, friendOperationAction, combinationMessagesList, this, dialog);
    messagesRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration((StickyRecyclerHeadersAdapter) messagesAdapter));
    findLastFriendsRequest();

    messagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);
    scrollMessagesToBottom();
}

@Override
protected void updateMessagesList() {
    initActualExtras();
    checkForCorrectChat();

    int oldMessagesCount = messagesAdapter.getAllItems().size();

    this.combinationMessagesList = createCombinationMessagesList();
    Log.d(TAG, "combinationMessagesList = " + combinationMessagesList);
    messagesAdapter.setList(combinationMessagesList);
    findLastFriendsRequest();

    checkForScrolling(oldMessagesCount);
}

private void initActualExtras() {
    opponentUser = (User) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_OPPONENT);
    dialog = (Dialog) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_DIALOG);
}

@Override
public void notifyChangedUserStatus(int userId, boolean online) {
    super.notifyChangedUserStatus(userId, online);

    if (opponentUser != null && opponentUser.getUserId() == userId) {
        setOnlineStatus(opponentUser);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.private_dialog_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean isFriend = DataManager.getInstance().getFriendDataManager().getByUserId(
            opponentUser.getUserId()) != null;
    if (!isFriend && item.getItemId() != android.R.id.home) {
        ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.dialog_user_is_not_friend);
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_audio_call:
            callToUser(opponentUser, QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO);
            break;
        case R.id.switch_camera_toggle:
            callToUser(opponentUser, QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO);
            break;
        default:
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void checkMessageSendingPossibility() {
    boolean enable = dataManager.getFriendDataManager().existsByUserId(opponentUser.getUserId()) && isNetworkAvailable();
    checkMessageSendingPossibility(enable);
}

@OnClick(R.id.toolbar)
void openProfile(View view) {
    UserProfileActivity.start(this, opponentUser.getUserId());
}

private void initFields() {
    chatHelperIdentifier = QBService.PRIVATE_CHAT_HELPER;
    friendOperationAction = new FriendOperationAction();
    friendObserver = new FriendObserver();
    initActualExtras();
//        opponentUser = (User)     getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_OPPONENT);
//        dialog = (Dialog) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_DIALOG);
    combinationMessagesList = createCombinationMessagesList();
    title = opponentUser.getFullName();
}

private void addObservers() {
    dataManager.getFriendDataManager().addObserver(friendObserver);
}

private void deleteObservers() {
    dataManager.getFriendDataManager().deleteObserver(friendObserver);
}

private void findLastFriendsRequest() {
    ((PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter) messagesAdapter).findLastFriendsRequestMessagesPosition();
    messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setOnlineStatus(User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        if (friendListHelper != null) {
            String offlineStatus = getString(R.string.last_seen, DateUtils.toTodayYesterdayShortDateWithoutYear2(user.getLastLogin()),
                    DateUtils.formatDateSimpleTime(user.getLastLogin()));
            setActionBarSubtitle(
                    OnlineStatusUtils.getOnlineStatus(this, friendListHelper.isUserOnline(user.getUserId()), offlineStatus));
        }
    }
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    sendMessage(true);
}

private void callToUser(User user, QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType) {
    if (!isChatInitializedAndUserLoggedIn()) {
        ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.call_chat_service_is_initializing);
        return;
    }
    List<QBUser> qbUserList = new ArrayList<>(1);
    qbUserList.add(UserFriendUtils.createQbUser(user));
    CallActivity.start(PrivateDialogActivity.this, qbUserList, qbConferenceType, null);
}

private void acceptUser(final int userId) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        if (!isChatInitializedAndUserLoggedIn()) {
            ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.call_chat_service_is_initializing);
            return;
        }

        showProgress();
        QBAcceptFriendCommand.start(this, userId);
    } else {
        ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.dlg_fail_connection);
        return;
    }
}

private void rejectUser(final int userId) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        if (!isChatInitializedAndUserLoggedIn()) {
            ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.call_chat_service_is_initializing);
            return;
        }

        showRejectUserDialog(userId);
    } else {
        ToastUtils.longToast(R.string.dlg_fail_connection);
        return;
    }
}

private void showRejectUserDialog(final int userId) {
    User user = DataManager.getInstance().getUserDataManager().get(userId);
    if (user == null) {
        return;
    }

    TwoButtonsDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            getString(R.string.dialog_message_reject_friend, user.getFullName()),
            new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    super.onPositive(dialog);
                    showProgress();
                    QBRejectFriendCommand.start(PrivateDialogActivity.this, userId);
                }
            });
}

private void checkForCorrectChat() {
    Dialog updatedDialog = null;
    if (dialog != null) {
        updatedDialog = dataManager.getDialogDataManager().getByDialogId(dialog.getDialogId());
    } else {
        finish();
    }

    if (updatedDialog == null) {
        finish();
    } else {
        dialog = updatedDialog;
    }
}

private class FriendOperationAction implements FriendOperationListener {

    @Override
    public void onAcceptUserClicked(int position, int userId) {
        operationItemPosition = position;
        acceptUser(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRejectUserClicked(int position, int userId) {
        operationItemPosition = position;
        rejectUser(userId);
    }
}

private class AcceptFriendSuccessAction implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
        ((PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter) messagesAdapter).clearLastRequestMessagePosition();
        messagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(operationItemPosition);
        startLoadDialogMessages();
        hideProgress();
    }
}

private class RejectFriendSuccessAction implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
        ((PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter) messagesAdapter).clearLastRequestMessagePosition();
        messagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(operationItemPosition);
        startLoadDialogMessages();
        hideProgress();
    }
}

private class FriendObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        if (data != null && data.equals(FriendDataManager.OBSERVE_KEY)) {
            checkForCorrectChat();
            checkMessageSendingPossibility();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my own mistake it code, i made the code work by changing messagesAdapter.setList(combinationmessagesList)
to
messagesAdapter.setList(combinationMessages);